# A question about ext2_sb_info

Tags: ext2

I study the ext2_sb_info structure (the memory data structure for ext2 superblock) and i noticed the existence of a field declared as

u32 s_next_generation;

I searched the web but it was not possible to find its role. Does anyone knows what is the purpose of this field? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Study the ext3 superblock data structure, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s_next_generation` stores the value that [will be used as the next new inode](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.7/source/fs/ext2/ialloc.c#L574)’s [generation](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.7/source/fs/ext2/ext2.h#L326).

The generation is used for [old-style NFSv2 file handles](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.7/source/include/uapi/linux/nfsd/nfsfh.h#L31).